# CSS - create 3 columns using css / Ordered

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a 3 column list with an ordered list using css?

1. Apples
2. Oranges
3. Lemons

Right now it is showing an unordered list even though the code is showing ordered.

Example: 1. Apples would be the first column and Oranges would be the second column instead of Apples in the first column and Oranges in the first below it.

```
<style> ol{margin-bottom:20px; overflow:hidden; width:600px;}
li{display:inline; float:left; line-height:1px;}
#two li {width:50%;}
#three li {width:33.333%;}
#four li {width:25%;}
#six li {width:16.666%;}
</style>




<code>
<ol id="3">
<li>
    <div class="fruit">
        apples
        oranges
        lemons
        etc..
    </div>
</li>
</ol>
  </code>
```

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you want to do.  Do you want columns or an ordered list?

Comment: Also, show us real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ul>` is an unordered list. Use `<ol>` for ordered list.

```
<ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ol>​
```

Here's a working example: [w3schools tryit](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists)

Comment: Hi Flem, I made the change to my code from UL to OL and it is still not recognized.

Comment: See the example. Does that work for you? What browser are you using? Do you use any third party CSS files/tools? Are you overriding the user agent styles?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by flem,

you code should look something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style> ol{margin-bottom:20px; overflow:hidden; width:600px;}
li{display:inline; float:left; line-height:15px;}
#two li {width:50%;}
#three li {width:33.333%;}
#four li {width:25%;}
#six li {width:16.666%;}
</style>
<body>

<h4>An Ordered List:</h4>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why do you defined #two, #trhee etc.

Comment: I will use a properties file to call the actual number because this file will be used more than once. So another instance might want to use 3 columns, 4, etc.